# Applying filters to a table

Tags: c#, linq

I've written a lengthy procedure that I call a few times to apply filters defined by the customer to a table, as I didn't see how I could turn my **column name string** into a **LINQ column** and how I could turn my **action string** into an **action on a string** in such way that the function can be used in the LINQ query like:

```
private void applyFilterAction(ref IQueryable<TempArticle> products, FilterAction action)
{
    products = from p in products where MAGIC(p, action.Column).ToLower().MAGIC2(action.Action, action.Value) == action.AddOrKill select p;
}
```

I wrote this instead as a temporary solution:

```
private void applyFilterAction(ref IQueryable<TempArticle> products, FilterAction action)
{
    var actionValue = action.Value.ToLower();
    var column = action.Column;

    if (action.Action.Equals("StartsWith"))
    {
        if (column.Equals("Description"))           products = from p in products where p.Description.ToLower().StartsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("LongDescription"))  products = from p in products where p.LongDescription.ToLower().StartsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Provider"))         products = from p in products where p.Provider.ToLower().StartsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("ProviderCode"))     products = from p in products where p.ProviderCode.ToLower().StartsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Publisher"))        products = from p in products where p.Publisher.ToLower().StartsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("PublisherCode"))    products = from p in products where p.PublisherCode.ToLower().StartsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Custom1"))          products = from p in products where p.Custom1.ToLower().StartsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Custom2"))          products = from p in products where p.Custom2.ToLower().StartsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Custom3"))          products = from p in products where p.Custom3.ToLower().StartsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("EanCode"))          products = from p in products where p.EanCode.ToLower().StartsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    }

    else if (action.Action.Equals("EndsWith"))
    {
        if (column.Equals("Description"))           products = from p in products where p.Description.ToLower().EndsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("LongDescription"))  products = from p in products where p.LongDescription.ToLower().EndsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Provider"))         products = from p in products where p.Provider.ToLower().EndsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("ProviderCode"))     products = from p in products where p.ProviderCode.ToLower().EndsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Publisher"))        products = from p in products where p.Publisher.ToLower().EndsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("PublisherCode"))    products = from p in products where p.PublisherCode.ToLower().EndsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Custom1"))          products = from p in products where p.Custom1.ToLower().EndsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Custom2"))          products = from p in products where p.Custom2.ToLower().EndsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Custom3"))          products = from p in products where p.Custom3.ToLower().EndsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("EanCode"))          products = from p in products where p.EanCode.ToLower().EndsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    }

    else if (action.Action.Equals("Contains"))
    {
        if (column.Equals("Description"))           products = from p in products where p.Description.ToLower().Contains(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("LongDescription"))  products = from p in products where p.LongDescription.ToLower().Contains(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Provider"))         products = from p in products where p.Provider.ToLower().Contains(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("ProviderCode"))     products = from p in products where p.ProviderCode.ToLower().Contains(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Publisher"))        products = from p in products where p.Publisher.ToLower().Contains(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("PublisherCode"))    products = from p in products where p.PublisherCode.ToLower().Contains(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Custom1"))          products = from p in products where p.Custom1.ToLower().Contains(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Custom2"))          products = from p in products where p.Custom2.ToLower().Contains(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Custom3"))          products = from p in products where p.Custom3.ToLower().Contains(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("EanCode"))          products = from p in products where p.EanCode.ToLower().Contains(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    }

    else if (action.Action.Equals("Exact"))
    {
        if (column.Equals("Description"))           products = from p in products where p.Description.ToLower().Equals(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("LongDescription"))  products = from p in products where p.LongDescription.ToLower().Equals(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Provider"))         products = from p in products where p.Provider.ToLower().Equals(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("ProviderCode"))     products = from p in products where p.ProviderCode.ToLower().Equals(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Publisher"))        products = from p in products where p.Publisher.ToLower().Equals(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("PublisherCode"))    products = from p in products where p.PublisherCode.ToLower().Equals(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Custom1"))          products = from p in products where p.Custom1.ToLower().Equals(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Custom2"))          products = from p in products where p.Custom2.ToLower().Equals(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("Custom3"))          products = from p in products where p.Custom3.ToLower().Equals(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
        else if (column.Equals("EanCode"))          products = from p in products where p.EanCode.ToLower().Equals(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    }
}
```

It filters products based on an `action` object that contains:

- `column`: Column of the product table that needs to be filtered.
- `action`: The action to perform on the strings coming from that column.
- `value`: The value to compare against using the action.

Could I write this in a better way? I didn't get the switch statements in the MAGIC functions to LINQify.

Comment: Is there any reason you went for a ref parameter rather than returning IQueryable<TempArticle>?

Comment: Looked this up, seems I should avoid ref/out parameters, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. **YOU HAVE A LOT OF CODE REPEATING ITSELF** - it definitely means something. Basically you have two fields to consider - `action` and `column`. Since all your columns are considered to be strings so you can separate **a)** logic which determines which column to take and **b)** logic which determines how to filter columns. This will lead to dramatical changes in your code.

   Here is a sample:

   ```
   private void applyFilterAction(ref IQueryable<TempArticle> products, FilterAction action)
   {
       var actionValue = action.Value.ToLower();
       var column = action.Column;

       Func<TempArticle, string> valueExtractor;
       // determining field
       if (column.Equals("Description")) valueExtractor = p => p.Description;
       else if (column.Equals("LongDescription")) valueExtractor = p => p.LongDescription;
       else if (column.Equals("Provider")) valueExtractor = p => p.Provider;
       else if (column.Equals("ProviderCode")) valueExtractor = p => p.ProviderCode;
       else if (column.Equals("Publisher")) valueExtractor = p => p.Publisher;
       else if (column.Equals("PublisherCode")) valueExtractor = p => p.PublisherCode;
       else if (column.Equals("Custom1")) valueExtractor = p => p.Custom1;
       else if (column.Equals("Custom2")) valueExtractor = p => p.Custom2;
       else if (column.Equals("Custom3")) valueExtractor = p => p.Custom3;
       else if (column.Equals("EanCode")) valueExtractor = p => p.EanCode;
       else throw new NotSupportedException(column);

       Predicate<string> filteringPredicate;

       // determining predicate
       if (action.Action.Equals("StartsWith")) filteringPredicate = s => s.StartsWith(actionValue);
       else if (action.Action.Equals("EndsWith")) filteringPredicate = s => s.EndsWith(actionValue);
       else if (action.Action.Equals("Contains")) filteringPredicate = s => s.Contains(actionValue);
       else if (action.Action.Equals("Exact")) filteringPredicate = s => s.Equals(actionValue);
       else throw new NotSupportedException(action.Action);

       products = from p in products where filteringPredicate(valueExtractor(p).ToLower()) == action.AddOrKill select p;
   }
   ```

   This approach is much better but I would go even further. Instead of this `if` blocks I would use dictionaries which will map input string into corresponding delegates .
   It has nothing to do with LINQ yet, only common sense. This was the main part. My other points are:
2. **UpperCamelCase**?
3. `action.AddOrKill` looks very strange. It took me a while to understand what are you trying to achieve with it. It looks very weird and should be rewritten in some other, more developer-friendly way.
4. I would not use such a method signature - void with ref parameter. It doesn't look solid with existing LINQ methods and there is no point in having such a signature. I would use regular LINQ `IQueryable MethodName(IQueryable<> source, ...other parameters)`.
5. I believe in such cases you should create fluent interface - it will improve code readability a lot. Especially in implementing `NOT` functionality.

Comment: +1 1) Didn't learned about functors in C# yet, pretty interesting and once you know it's indeed common sense. You were first so you most likely be accepted when I'm done reading. 2) Where did I go wrong? everything is private local so I think lowelCamelCase suffices in this case. 3) Well, the user can specify if he still wants to include or exclude the products that went through that filter; spares us both from having to create "Doesn't Start With" entries and such things. 4) Hmm, so as it is a reference type I don't need ref, I'll try. 5) How do you mean? I will extract the determining parts.

Comment: 2) In C# private methods are usually also named in UpperCC. 4) No, `ref` is needed if you are going to change products, but I believe you should return it instead of modifying that one which was passed as a parameter 5) If you are only started learning C# then maybe you should not do it, but I would prefer to see smth like `products.Where.Column("Description").Equals("DDD").And.Not.Column("LongDescription").StartsWith("SSS")` - this can be implemented

Comment: Got this working using a workaround by using `ToExpandable` and `Invoke`, as I'm using LINQ to Entities it started complaining about the different Func conversions that it had to do...

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything LINQ related that could be done here... but it looks to me like all the contents of all the IF statements are the same. Perhaps that should be extracted into a method?

Also:

```
ToLower().StartsWith(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill
```

Should be

```
StartsWith(actionValue, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == action.AddOrKill
```

Using `ToLower` for case insensitive string comparisons doesn't respect the culture of the current system, and will give wrong results for several languages (particularly those with 3 cases rather than 2). Plus, it's slower, because you're converting the entire string, rather than simply running comparisons on the beginning of the string.

---

EDIT: I see the difference between the IF blocks now. It's been a while since I've played with C#, so I'm not entirely sure this will compile out of the box, but it should give you the idea. Basically you pass around a functor rather than replicating the if block over and over again:

```
private void applyFilterAction(ref IQueryable<TempArticle> products, FilterAction action)
{
    var actionValue = action.Value.ToLower();
    var column = action.Column;
    Func<string, string, bool> comparer;

    if (action.Action.Equals("StartsWith"))
    {
        comparer = (a, b) => a.StartsWith(b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
    else if (action.Action.Equals("EndsWith"))
    {
        comparer = (a, b) => a.EndsWith(b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
    else if (action.Action.Equals("Contains"))
    {
        comparer = (a, b) => a.Contains(b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
    else if (action.Action.Equals("Exact"))
    {
        comparer = (a, b) => a.Equals(b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    if (column == "Description")           products = from p in products where comparer(p.Description, actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    else if (column == "LongDescription")  products = from p in products where comparer(p.LongDescription, actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    else if (column == "Provider")         products = from p in products where comparer(p.Provider, actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    else if (column == "ProviderCode")     products = from p in products where comparer(p.ProviderCode, actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    else if (column == "Publisher")        products = from p in products where comparer(p.Publisher, actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    else if (column == "PublisherCode")    products = from p in products where comparer(p.PublisherCode, actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    else if (column == "Custom1")          products = from p in products where comparer(p.Custom1, actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    else if (column == "Custom2")          products = from p in products where comparer(p.Custom2, actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    else if (column == "Custom3")          products = from p in products where comparer(p.Custom3, actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    else if (column == "EanCode")          products = from p in products where comparer(p.EanCode, actionValue) == action.AddOrKill select p;
}
```

Like I said, it's been a while since I've messed with C#, so this might not work :)

Comment: -1 because extracting them into a method is LINQ related, as it would result in a method inside the LINQ query, the IFs you see determine the Column and the String Comparison Action in the LINQ query, I wanted to add the tag [extract-method] but I need 150 reputation for that. I want to know how to do it, because it usually gives a vague error that says that the method can't be converted to LINQ.

Comment: +1 beceause of the unrelated hint; although its blazing fast as is, your suggestion makes it even faster. Still, the current code is ugly and prone to errors. :-(

Comment: @TomWij: What's different about the contents of the IF blocks? It looks to me like they are identical. EDIT: Oh, I see now. Give me a sec.

Comment: +1 this seems a good approach and does take away lines without having me to go through the nasty LINQ compilation.

Comment: Seems LINQ to Entities only allows this for `Equals`, using `ToUpper` at the moment and will look if another solution exists that can be EF4 LINQified.

Answer (score 2):

If you can edit the `TempArticle` class, the best way would be to add an indexer to the class that switches on the column name and returns the value of that column. Your filter code would then be

```
private void applyFilterAction(ref IQueryable<TempArticle> products, FilterAction action)
{
    if (action.Action == "StartsWith")
    {
        products = from p in products where p[action.Column].StartsWith(action.Value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    }
    else
    {
        products = from p in products where p[action.Column].EndsWith(action.Value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    }
}
```

In case you can't change `TempArticle`'s definition and assuming `action.Column` equals the name of the corresponding property in `TempArticle`, you can use compiled Expressions as accessors:

```
static class PropertyAccessor<T>
{
    static Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>> propGetters;
    static Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>> PropGetters
    {
        get
        {
            if (propGetters == null)
            {
                Initialize();
            }
            return propGetters;
        }
    }

    static Dictionary<string, Action<T, object>> propSetters;
    static Dictionary<string, Action<T, object>> PropSetters
    {
        get
        {
            if (propSetters == null)
            {
                Initialize();
            }
            return propSetters;
        }
    }

    static void Initialize()
    {
        propGetters = new Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>>();
        propSetters = new Dictionary<string, Action<T, object>>();

        var type = typeof(T);

        foreach (var pi in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            if (pi.CanRead)
            {
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "instance");

                Expression<Func<T, object>> lambda;

                if (pi.PropertyType.IsValueType)
                {
                    lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.TypeAs(Expression.Property(parameter, pi.Name), typeof(object)), parameter);
                }
                else
                {
                    lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Property(parameter, pi.Name), parameter);
                }

                propGetters.Add(pi.Name, lambda.Compile());
            }

            if (pi.CanWrite)
            {
                var paramExpT = Expression.Parameter(type, "instance");
                var paramExpObj = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");
                var setterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, object>>(Expression.Call(paramExpT, pi.GetSetMethod(), Expression.ConvertChecked(paramExpObj, pi.PropertyType)), paramExpT, paramExpObj);
                propSetters.Add(pi.Name, setterLambda.Compile());
            }
        }
    }

    public static object Get(T instance, string propName)
    {
        return PropGetters[propName](instance);
    }

    public static string[] GetAccessorKeys
    {
        get
        {
            return PropGetters.Keys.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static void Set(T instance, string propName, object value)
    {
        PropSetters[propName](instance, value);
    }

    public static string[] SetAccessorKeys
    {
        get
        {
            return PropSetters.Keys.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

`applyFilterAction`:

```
private void applyFilterAction(ref IQueryable<TempArticle> products, FilterAction action)
{
    if (action.Action == "StartsWith")
    {
        products = from p in products where ((string)PropertyAccessor<TempArticle>.Get(p, action.Column)).StartsWith(action.Value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    }
    else
    {
        products = from p in products where ((string)PropertyAccessor<TempArticle>.Get(p, action.Column)).EndsWith(action.Value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == action.AddOrKill select p;
    }
}
```

The accessors are compiled only once for each type, but are slightly slower than direct access, partly because of the type casting. (You can use `string` instead of `object` if you filter by `pi.PropertyType` in the initialize loop.)

Other than that, I agree with Snowbear on the coding style and pattern use. This interface looks quite counterintuitive and it's definitely never a good idea to name a flag `<Action>or<Opposite>`.

Part of the accessor code taken from:
[Fast Dynamic Property Access with C# (Comments)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/fast_dynamic_properties.aspx)

Edit:

If you want more speed, you should use [HyperDescriptor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx) instead: It writes IL directly and is really fast. In .NET 4, you need to [fix the security permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105763/does-hyperdescriptor-work-when-built-in-net-4/3105883#3105883).

Comment: +1 I'm using Code First, my guess is that the first thing will probably result in the LINQ problem. The second is a valid solution, still it looks like a dirty way to do it so I'm going for Snowbear's solution...

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I can introduce a trimmed down version of your second solution for the dictionary in @Snowbear's solution. Thinking about it again your solution would allow code reuse if it works so you might as well be most likely accepted, I'll think about it... Worst case I'm going for bounties. I don't need rep here... :D

Comment: I added a link to HyperDescriptor, that way it's almost as fast as direct access but still reusable. It's a bit more hacky though...

Answer (score 1):

I would write some helper extension methods:

```
public static class FilterActionHelper {
    private static Dictionary<string, Func<string, Func<string, bool>>> actions = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, Func<string, bool>>>() {
        { "StartsWith", x => y => x.StartsWith(y) },
        { "EndsWith", x => y => x.EndsWith(y) },
        { "Contains", x => y => x.Contains(y) }
    };

    private static Dictionary<string, Func<TempArticle, string>> propertySelectors = new Dictionary<string, Func<TempArticle, string>>() {
        { "Description", x => x.Description },
        { "LongDescription", x => x.LongDescription },
        { "Provider", x => x.Provider },
        { "ProviderCode", x => x.ProviderCode },
        { "Publisher", x => x.Publisher },
        { "PublisherCode", x => x.PublisherCode },
        { "Custom1", x => x.Custom1 },
        { "Custom2", x => x.Custom2 },
        { "Custom3", x => x.Custom3 },
    };

    public static bool HasAction(string actionName) {
        return actions.ContainsKey(actionName);
    }

    public static Func<string, bool> GetAction(this string str, string actionName) {
        return actions[actionName](str);
    }

    public static bool HasProperty(string propertyName) {
        return propertySelectors.ContainsKey(propertyName);
    }

    public static string GetProperty(this TempArticle product, string propertyName) {
        return propertySelectors[propertyName](product);
    }
}
```

which would allow the more succinct code:

```
private void ApplyFilterAction(ref IQueryable<TempArticle> products, FilterAction action) {
    var actionValue = action.Value.ToLower();
    var column = action.Column;

    if (!FilterActionHelper.HasAction(action.Action)) {
        return;
    }

    if (!FilterActionHelper.HasProperty(column)) {
        return;
    }

    products = from p in products
               where p.GetProperty(column).ToLower().GetAction(action.Action)(actionValue) == action.AddOrKill
               select p;
}
```

The use of dictionaries makes it easy to add new properties and actions. The extension methods then make it a lot easier to use those dictionaries in a way that reads well.

Another solution you may find easier is to make FilterAction generic:

```
public class FilterAction<T> {
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Func<T, string> GetProperty { get; set; }
    public Func<string, string, bool> Action { get; set; }
    public bool AddOrKill { get; set; }

    public bool Matches(T t) {
        var filterValue = Value.ToLower();
        var propertValue = GetProperty(t).ToLower();
        return (Action(propertyValue, filterValue)) == AddOrKill);
    }
}

…

FilterAction<TempArticle> filter = new FilterAction<TempArticle>();
filter.Value = "foo";
filter.GetProperty = x => x.Custom1;
filter.Action = x, y => x.StartsWith(y);
filter.AddOrKill = false;

var products = from p in products where filter.Matches(p) select p;
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for working it out more, although generic won't work given that it is a Code First Entity.